# Swift 4 ,CoreData: error: Failed to load model named textTabelView

Tags: ios, core-data, appdelegate, swift4

When I using Swift4 in Xcode 9 gives me

> 2017-11-13 10:17:15.807151+0800 textTabelView[1146:53409] [discovery]
>   errors encountered while discovering extensions: Error Domain=PlugInKit Code=13 "query cancelled" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=query cancelled}
>   2017-11-13 10:17:16.369075+0800 textTabelView[1146:52958] [error] error:  Failed
>   to load model named textTabelView CoreData: error:  Failed to load model named textTabelView

My Codes:

```
@IBAction func savaArea(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

    area = AreaMO(context: appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext)
    area.area = areaText.text
    area.province = provinceText.text
    area.part = partText.text
    area.isVisited = visitedLabel.text
    if let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(coverImageView.image!, 0.8){
        area.image = NSData(data: imageData) as Data
    }
    print("saving...")
    appDelegate.saveContext()

    performSegue(withIdentifier: "unwindToArea", sender: self)

}
```

The AppDelegat.swift about CoreData:

```
// MARK: - Core Data stack

lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {

    let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "textTabelView")

    ...
}
```

i'm sure I did import the CoreData correctly.

The project can build normally, but when I touch the button (which @IBaction is), the warning was printed in the console and the app crashed

How can I fixed it?

Comment: The name used in your persistent container should match the name of your xcdatamodel file.

Answer (score 2):

This is the same error you would get if the name of your NSPersistentContainer parameter did not match the name of your xcdatamodeld file. Possible solutions:

1. Double check that the the data model is named "textTabelView.xcdatamodeld",
2. delete the old xcdatamodeld file and create a new one if the name is corrupted with some invisible characters, or
3. clean build the app folder (⌥⇧⌘K) (ie option+shift+apple+K).

Good luck!